# How to fetch AppleID via CKRecordID?

Tags: swift, cloudkit

How can I fetch the recently logged in iCloud user's `AppleID`, `firstName`, `lastName` via `CKRecordID` from CloudKit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **firstName**, **lastName** you can  use this way, e-mail / appleID I still do not know:

```
var defaultContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
var publicDatabase = defaultContainer.publicCloudDatabase

defaultContainer.discoverUserInfoWithUserRecordID(recordID, {userInfo, error in

    println("firstName: \(userInfo.firstName?) lastName: \(userInfo.lastName?)")

    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to fetch the User Record ID and then you check that there isn't an error, if so, then you can fetch the UserInfo for the ID that you just fetched and use the result the access the information that you want

```
container.fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler({
        userID, error in
        if (!error) {
            container.discoverUserInfoWithUserRecordID(userID, {
                userInfo, error in
                })
        }
        })
```

You can then use the `userInfo` to find out the firstName and lastName simply by using dot notation.

eg. `userInfo.firstName`

I assume by the fact that you are using CloudKit that you are a registered apple developer and so i recommend you watch both of the WWDC videos on the topic. With the exception of subscriptions which don't work at the time of writing this, everything in the video is incredibly useful and in fact covers the question you asked. After watching them, you may also want to pick apart apples own app which they made with CloudKit, paying careful attention to AAPLCloudManager. The link below is for this app. Hope this helps!

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/CloudAtlas/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014599